# AWS SageMaker: No Response Received from invoke_endpoint (Timeout)

Tags: amazon-web-services, pytorch, amazon-sagemaker

I am experimenting with the AWS SageMaker Model Hosting service and have been following this tutorial https://tudorvladstefan.medium.com/deploying-pytorch-models-in-aws-sagemaker-7c48d6308df1

The public repository can be found here
https://github.com/tdrvlad/pytorch-sagemaker-deployment

I have published my model.tar.gz file onto S3 as instructed, and successfully deployed the model on SageMaker (my endpoint has the "InService" status shown. All these were done by running

```
python sagemaker_deployment.py
```

However, when I tried to run an inference with

```
python predict.py
```

I never received anything back as my response, until I received the 60 seconds timeout error

```
An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation:
```

As a debug attempt, I went onto CloudWatch --> log groups --> log stream (for the target endpoint), in which shows the following logs:

```
2024-02-21T22:04:38,699 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1.0 TS_METRICS - Requests5XX.Count:1.0|#Level:Host|#hostname:container-0.local,timestamp:1708553078
```

```
2024-02-21T22:04:43,698 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1.0 ACCESS_LOG - /169.254.178.2:41038 "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 500 0
```

Anyone has idea about what these logs mean? Do they represent errors? If so, could they be the reason I didn't receive back any response from the invocation, or can there be other causes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be happening due to few issues -

1. The request is timing out beyond the 60s limit in SageMaker Hosting.
2. SageMaker uses /PING and /Invocations to respond, the fact that you are seeing 500 errors on /Ping tells me that you might not be reaching the container successfully.

To debug this issue, I would advise you to 1/ Try local Inference within your SageMaker notebook instance( or ec2) to run the container and check for any issues. 2/ Add debug logs into your container code( model.py) to see where the issue is coming from. The error in CW is very generic and the issue cannot be determined.